# Ionic / Angular HttpClient.post does two server posts: "OPTIONS" and "POST"

Tags: javascript, php, angular, post, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular / Ionic. I have an Ionic form that posts data to PHP.

Here is what my Angular code looks like:

My event service:

```
event-service-rest.ts:

    postAnEventRest(headers = null, params = null) {
    return this.http.post(eventApiURL, { headers, params });
}
```

The event TypeScript page:

```
create-event.ts

postAnEvent () {

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
.append('Authorization', 'this.authHeader')
.append('Accept', 'application/json')
.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

const body = this.event;

this.eventService.postAnEventRest(headers, body)
.subscribe((data: any) => {
this.event = data;
},
(error: any) => {
console.log(error);
});
}
```

Here is what my PHP code looks like:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$event_title = $data['params']['event_title'];
$event_desc = $data['params']['event_desc'];

// Singleton Database Library - custom code for entering into database
$result = $db->insert('events', $event_title, $event_desc);
?>
```

The Angular App posts two posts into the PHP server. The code creates one null entry into the database plus another entry with the correct data entered into the database.

So, I looked at the Apache log file (pasted below) and there are two entries. One as "OPTIONS" and one as "POST" with each Ionic post request:

```
99.90.86.4 - - [13/Jan/2018:13:21:27 -0800] "OPTIONS /calendar/events-json2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
99.90.86.4 - - [13/Jan/2018:13:21:27 -0800] "POST /calendar/events-json2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:8100/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
```

I appreciate any help:
1. What I'm doing wrong that causes two posts to the server?
2. Is this the correct way to structure and write Ionic code to post data (To create service / provider page that posts the data and do the subscribe in the TypeScript page)

Comment: only 1 POST request is executed, the OPTIONS one is called preflight request, this is part of the CORS mechanism

Comment: Thank you for responding, sorry, I still cannot figure out what part of my code causes two entries in the database, one null and one full data. I tested my PHP code by visiting the PHP page directly and it only enters one entry into the database, so there is something wrong with my Ionic / Angular code that does one null post and one full post.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, but it's still an HTTP request

Comment: @BernieK, check how you handle OPTIONS request on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like as part of CORS mechanism, there will be the OPTIONS request to the server.

I tried to ignore all OPTIONS request using .htaccess in order to solve this problem, but it did not help the situation. It seems like the OPTIONS request to the server must happen in order for the POST request to happen as part of CORS.

So, I just added the conditional code to check for POST requests in order to add the entry in the database and this solved the problem:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    $event_title = $data['params']['event_title'];
    $event_desc = $data['params']['event_desc'];

    // Singleton Database Library - custom code for entering into database
    $result = $db->insert('events', $event_title, $event_desc);
}
```